# unbalanced class metrics and scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn

Is there a standard way of dealing with unbalanced classes in scikit-learn?

One of the delights of sk-learn is that there is a consistent interface...

however, when classes are unbalanced [which seems a pretty common use case) this is not the case: IMO one does not want the classification, but a continuous variable between 0 and 1 such that you can compute auc_score ( or something similar)

so I can do auc_score(y,cf.predict_probas(X)) on logistic and a few other classifiers but I don't see any reason why I can't do basically the same for any decision_function [ eg RidgeClassifier ... etc], ie vary my threshold and monitor the false alarm, hit rates?

how do people do this? This is what I am doing (as ogrisel also suggested)

```
if hasattr(clf,'predict_proba'):
    proba=clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
    score=metrics.auc_score(y_test,proba)

elif hasattr(clf,'decision_function'):
    z=clf.decision_function(X_test)
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, z)
    score=metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
```

Comment: If you are using the 0.14-dev version, you can use the scorer interface btw :) http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-objects-defining-your-scoring-rules

Comment: Thanks andreas - I do plan to look at that in Linux [it looked great from the documentation]  , but am mainly windows user and build seemed a pain (eg BLAS/ATLAS)... but to confirm, would  grid_search.GridSearchCV and cross_validation.cross_val_score with scoring =roc_auc use proba or decision functions ( and not the predict output)

Comment: yes, this is exactly what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Using `decision_function` should work, otherwise this is a bug.